# Hiding the unity launcher and it's still opening apps

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher

I currently have compiz running with Ubuntu 12.04. I use the 'rotate cube' a lot and I like being able to click on the edges of the screen to rotate right and left.

With the introduction of the unity launcher I change this behaviour to being able to rotate right and left by clicking on the right edge with the left or right buttons. But old habits die hard and I tried (auto-)hiding the launcher and enabling rotate left by clicking on the left edge of the screen.

Unfortunately (while it does indeed rotate left) ubuntu still launches the app that would have been where I clicked if I hadn't of hidden the launcher.

I still want to utilize the launcher, I just don't want it open applications when it's hidden and I'm clicking on the left edge to rotate the cube

Is there anyway I can remove this behaviour?

Comment: I know this doesnt answer your question but why did you not undock all the apps from the launcher before you hid it. Then there would be nothing to click on, hidden or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 12.04 you can't disable launcher. It is by design.

Go to **System Settings > Appearance > Behavior** set the sensitivity to minimum. This should at least give you enough time to click on left edge.

Let us know the whether you succeed.

Comment: I tried this and while it prevents the launcher coming up the applications are still launching depending where I click on the edge :(

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to utilize the launcher (one of unity's key features) why not leverage the **Gnome Classic** interface at login.

To achieve this:  Follow the instructions in [this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Comment: I want to utilize the launcher, I just don't want it open applications when it's hidden and I'm clicking on the left edge to rotate the cube

Comment: I think web-e's answer is the best your going to get then.  I edited your question to include your comment for clarity. This will help future viewers of this q&a